# TLS 1.3 server socket with Java 11 and self-signed certificates

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, java-11, tls1.3

I want to create a simple TLS 1.3 server socket listener, which uses a self-signed certificate.

First I created a RSA public / private key pair:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -days 9125 -nodes -keyout test.key -out test.crt
```

I added the public and private key as a string in a simple Java program

```
public class TlsServer
{

    private static final String TEST_CRT = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
        // ...
        + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

    private static final String TEST_KEY
        = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
        // ...
        + "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

    private static final int PORT = 32333;

    private static final String TLS_PROTOCOL = "TLSv1.3";

    private static final String[] CIPHER_SUITES = new String[]
    {
        "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        new TlsServer().start();
    }

    private void start() throws Exception
    {
        //System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");

        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance(TLS_PROTOCOL);

        // Init Key Store.
        char[] password = "changeit".toCharArray();
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(null, password);
        Certificate cert = convertCertificate(TEST_CRT);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("test_crt", cert);
        Key pk = new SecretKeySpec(TEST_KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), "RSA");
        ks.setKeyEntry("test_key", pk, password, new Certificate[]
        {
            cert
        });

        // Init Key Manager Factory.
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(ks, password);

        // Init Trust Manager Factory.
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ks);

        ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        SSLServerSocket serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket) ctx.getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(PORT);
        serverSocket.setNeedClientAuth(false);
        serverSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]
        {
            TLS_PROTOCOL
        });
        serverSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(CIPHER_SUITES);

        System.out.printf("Server started on port %d%n", PORT);
        while (true)
        {
            try (SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept())
            {
                System.out.println("Accept new connection: " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                byte[] data = new byte[2048];
                int len = is.read(data);
                if (len <= 0)
                {
                    throw new IOException("No data received");
                }
                System.out.printf("Server received %d bytes: %s%n", len, new String(data, 0, len));
                os.write(data, 0, len);
                os.flush();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private Certificate convertCertificate(String cert) throws CertificateException
    {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(cert.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        return certFactory.generateCertificate(in);
    }
}
```

Java Version

```
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode)
```

The server starts and listens to the connection, but if I try to access the server with a client (e.g. curl, Chrome or a simple Java-Client), I get the following error:

```
Server started on port 32333
Accept new connection: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:49966
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No available authentication scheme
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:336)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:283)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.onProduceCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:972)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.produce(CertificateMessage.java:961)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:436)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.goServerHello(ClientHello.java:1234)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1170)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:852)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:813)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1418)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1324)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:829)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:920)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at TlsServer.start(TlsServer.java:143)
    at TlsServer.main(TlsServer.java:95)
```

The debug output look like this:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.010 CEST|ServerHello.java:577|Produced ServerHello handshake message (
"ServerHello": {
  "server version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "78 B9 53 93 89 F9 8F 8C 2B 03 33 72 5D 21 4D A5 DC 42 59 CE 54 24 CD 75 9F 26 15 09 FB 53 91 00",
  "session id"          : "EC 09 75 BD 7F 00 40 CB 9F DC F4 BA FD 03 57 82 6C D0 6E 4C 2D FD 79 AA 07 91 86 A8 1C A8 99 38",
  "cipher suite"        : "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301)",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "selected version": [TLSv1.3]
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "server_share": {
        "named group": x25519
        "key_exchange": {
          0000: B3 C2 7D 1D 77 D1 CE 3F   1D C2 15 0A 3A 21 B5 3B  ....w..?....:!.;
          0010: ED D0 BB 79 D1 C0 88 46   98 71 DD 2D 62 40 E1 1E  ...y...F.q.-b@..
        }
      },
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.010 CEST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:241|WRITE: TLS13 handshake, length = 122
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.011 CEST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:255|Raw write (
  0000: 16 03 03 00 7A 02 00 00   76 03 03 78 B9 53 93 89  ....z...v..x.S..
  0010: F9 8F 8C 2B 03 33 72 5D   21 4D A5 DC 42 59 CE 54  ...+.3r]!M..BY.T
  0020: 24 CD 75 9F 26 15 09 FB   53 91 00 20 EC 09 75 BD  $.u.&...S.. ..u.
  0030: 7F 00 40 CB 9F DC F4 BA   FD 03 57 82 6C D0 6E 4C  ..@.......W.l.nL
  0040: 2D FD 79 AA 07 91 86 A8   1C A8 99 38 13 01 00 00  -.y........8....
  0050: 2E 00 2B 00 02 03 04 00   33 00 24 00 1D 00 20 B3  ..+.....3.$... .
  0060: C2 7D 1D 77 D1 CE 3F 1D   C2 15 0A 3A 21 B5 3B ED  ...w..?....:!.;.
  0070: D0 BB 79 D1 C0 88 46 98   71 DD 2D 62 40 E1 1E     ..y...F.q.-b@..
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.017 CEST|SSLCipher.java:1840|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.018 CEST|SSLCipher.java:1994|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.018 CEST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:225|Raw write (
  0000: 14 03 03 00 01 01                                  ......
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.019 CEST|ServerNameExtension.java:527|Ignore unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.019 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.019 CEST|MaxFragExtension.java:469|Ignore unavailable max_fragment_length extension
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.019 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.020 CEST|AlpnExtension.java:365|Ignore unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.020 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.020 CEST|EncryptedExtensions.java:137|Produced EncryptedExtensions message (
"EncryptedExtensions": [
  "supported_groups (10)": {
    "versions": [x25519, secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, x448, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
  }
]
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.020 CEST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:241|WRITE: TLS13 handshake, length = 32
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.028 CEST|SSLCipher.java:2036|Plaintext before ENCRYPTION (
  0000: 08 00 00 1C 00 1A 00 0A   00 16 00 14 00 1D 00 17  ................
  0010: 00 18 00 19 00 1E 01 00   01 01 01 02 01 03 01 04  ................
  0020: 16 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
  0030: 00                                                 .
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.028 CEST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:255|Raw write (
  0000: 17 03 03 00 41 7D 95 DC   2E 14 CB 2C B5 B3 D4 79  ....A......,...y
  0010: 67 4C D6 01 7E 7C EE 31   58 A3 63 33 E1 30 0E 3C  gL.....1X.c3.0.<
  0020: FB 73 DD 85 57 95 36 B5   93 17 73 3A E6 2E 6C A9  .s..W.6...s:..l.
  0030: A1 F0 49 15 93 28 39 A8   E3 ED D5 02 85 05 09 37  ..I..(9........7
  0040: 28 3F B3 52 62 94                                  (?.Rb.
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.028 CEST|X509Authentication.java:295|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.029 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.029 CEST|X509Authentication.java:295|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.029 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.029 CEST|X509Authentication.java:295|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.029 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.029 CEST|X509Authentication.java:295|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.029 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.029 CEST|X509Authentication.java:295|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.029 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.029 CEST|X509Authentication.java:295|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.029 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.029 CEST|X509Authentication.java:295|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.029 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.029 CEST|X509Authentication.java:295|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.029 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.030 CEST|X509Authentication.java:295|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.030 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.030 CEST|X509Authentication.java:295|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.030 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.030 CEST|X509Authentication.java:295|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.030 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.030 CEST|X509Authentication.java:295|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.030 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.030 CEST|X509Authentication.java:295|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.030 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_sha1
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.030 CEST|X509Authentication.java:295|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.030 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1083|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha1
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.030 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:1093|No available authentication scheme
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.031 CEST|TransportContext.java:341|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): No available authentication scheme (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No available authentication scheme
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:336)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:283)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.onProduceCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:972)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.produce(CertificateMessage.java:961)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:436)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.goServerHello(ClientHello.java:1234)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1170)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:852)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:813)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1418)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1324)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:829)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:920)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at TlsServer.start(TlsServer.java:143)
    at TlsServer.main(TlsServer.java:95)}

)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.031 CEST|SSLSessionImpl.java:784|Invalidated session:  Session(1622109721099|SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.031 CEST|SSLSessionImpl.java:784|Invalidated session:  Session(1622109733001|TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.031 CEST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:71|WRITE: TLS13 alert(handshake_failure), length = 2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.031 CEST|SSLCipher.java:2036|Plaintext before ENCRYPTION (
  0000: 02 28 15 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .(..............
  0010: 00 00 00                                           ...
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.032 CEST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:85|Raw write (
  0000: 17 03 03 00 23 96 86 5D   95 12 6A 81 E7 77 F0 B5  ....#..]..j..w..
  0010: 45 7F F3 A4 98 D9 1B E6   FF C7 C1 BC 5F 1B B4 55  E..........._..U
  0020: DD 5A FE B9 B1 98 47 CF                            .Z....G.
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.032 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1638|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-05-27 12:02:13.032 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1657|close the SSL connection (initiative)
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No available authentication scheme
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:336)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:283)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.onProduceCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:972)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.produce(CertificateMessage.java:961)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:436)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.goServerHello(ClientHello.java:1234)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1170)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:852)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:813)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1418)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1324)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:829)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:920)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at TlsServer.start(TlsServer.java:143)
    at TlsServer.main(TlsServer.java:95)
```

Does anyone know, if I miss something in the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta: I can't believe this isn't a dupe, but I can't find one.

SSL/TLS authentication uses [public-key or asymmetric cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) not secret-key or symmetric. Instead of this

```
    Key pk = new SecretKeySpec(TEST_KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), "RSA");
    ks.setKeyEntry("test_key", pk, password, new Certificate[]
    {
        cert
    });
```

do this

```
    byte[] der = Base64.getDecoder().decode(TEST_KEY.replaceAll("-----(BEGIN|END) PRIVATE KEY-----\r?\n","").replaceAll("\r?\n",""));
    // or make these changes already in the value coded as Michael Fehr did
    // or leave the internal breaks and use .getMimeDecoder() (but remove the BEGIN/END lines)
    PrivateKey pk = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA") .generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(der));
    ks.setKeyEntry("test_key", pk, password, new Certificate[]{cert} );
```

and then use that for `KeyManagerFactory.init` as you do now. You don't need to put the server's own cert in its TrustManager, you can just use `null` as the first argument to `SSLContext.init`, especially since you aren't asking for client auth. However, the *client(s) which connect to* your server *do* need this cert added to *their* truststores; for curl you can just use `--cacert $pemfile` on the command line, but other clients will be different and may be more complicated.

PS: the key and cert, and KeyManager and TrustManager if any, can be the same for 1.3 as for earlier protocols, except that DSA can no longer be used in 1.3; only the version and ciphersuites differ. However, [in 1.3 you have the *option* of using a cert restricted to RSA-PSS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-4.2.3) instead of plain RSA, and when creating from OpenSSL the keyfile also indicates this (although the key needn't be actually restricted).

Comment: Thank you, the PKCS8 conversion did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a second answer as the code is too long for pasting it in the first answer.

Yes, it is possible to run a TLS server using **temporary** trust- and keystores. I can't judge about any security issues this brings with it -so be care when using this code.

To get your code run out of the box I'm using a RSA private key and self signed certificate - I stripped out the "--- BEGIN ... END ---" and left only the (Base64 encoded) part to get the key/certificate. Dont't worry, it is a **sample key**:

```
public static X509Certificate getcertificate() throws CertificateException {
    String certificate = "MIIDSzCCAjMCBFc5m4cwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwajELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxCzAJ" +
            "BgNVBAgMAkNBMRIwEAYDVQQHDAlDdXBlcnRpbm8xDjAMBgNVBAoMBUR1bW15MQ4w" +
            "DAYDVQQLDAVEdW1teTEaMBgGA1UEAwwRZHVtbXkuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20wHhcNMTYw" +
            "NTE2MTAwNjM4WhcNMjYwNTE2MTAwNjM4WjBqMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzELMAkGA1UE" +
            "CAwCQ0ExEjAQBgNVBAcMCUN1cGVydGlubzEOMAwGA1UECgwFRHVtbXkxDjAMBgNV" +
            "BAsMBUR1bW15MRowGAYDVQQDDBFkdW1teS5leGFtcGxlLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZI" +
            "hvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMkbQD5byG7xnyOWVzeIwbtHVPem/LJlXAHc" +
            "WJwz8pZ75rGBnZmAtgunXU++yPTZZOgYTZpM+qQhrFy2Z1Di/vVzhlVpcOZBw1RB" +
            "lI3s2uQYaWVtBtKtNELYWXEbhfxVJFBs5lLmsYJufVasMT+3XzBERuIEUV43JTKS" +
            "5ttwkoVgYRX6KDrIj0hYA7ZmOB/y5E1BG2mLsSkX0SoTCpuhgYwlWO4kvYoGu9vH" +
            "SfugUzQBqSiE1yN+Qfl3+76U23Pmbm/by9n3M3AoULxk2XnQmgBYtzViV0f1E3rr" +
            "/77XvIydWLHB0kotpND+ZN4IvTwpr3v7Iy6wbofg+Ounvwf7MKMCAwEAATANBgkq" +
            "hkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAWRWiibTf9UZAlXr+2ZmBMMMONpBOUaSbexLNs6MahBmj" +
            "cdEwOQ+l5xAdV4xVEDoDhu0m1JeDXy6SXo7mYkM2l9u/uz7tRStuEiM+tbCDaclb" +
            "W/H5QOdpiIx9uh86cEgBpk4xUO5vSaLI/9uSKgGkTNAFrjy3ME3wfc0cd5ntS8ca" +
            "8xobcmQ59SYZb9Gi0u/YN9yro9RwGDL8O1Bmp9+9rn5hor/oOVGHlbz2MN43moSZ" +
            "EiIfegW9OWiaWqIGqBOXvoEGp0exN+lhhmonI3zdYCB0jss2QYm3E1IWqZUkNOg3" +
            "yulIxph3FYvF+cA/vTVlohq5VB3DsCrnkDmqbU2mlw==";
    byte[] encodedCertificate = Base64.getDecoder().decode(certificate);
    CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    return (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(encodedCertificate));
}

// don't worry, it is a sample rsa private key
public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    String privateKeyPem = "MIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQDJG0A+W8hu8Z8j" +
            "llc3iMG7R1T3pvyyZVwB3FicM/KWe+axgZ2ZgLYLp11Pvsj02WToGE2aTPqkIaxc" +
            "tmdQ4v71c4ZVaXDmQcNUQZSN7NrkGGllbQbSrTRC2FlxG4X8VSRQbOZS5rGCbn1W" +
            "rDE/t18wREbiBFFeNyUykubbcJKFYGEV+ig6yI9IWAO2Zjgf8uRNQRtpi7EpF9Eq" +
            "EwqboYGMJVjuJL2KBrvbx0n7oFM0AakohNcjfkH5d/u+lNtz5m5v28vZ9zNwKFC8" +
            "ZNl50JoAWLc1YldH9RN66/++17yMnVixwdJKLaTQ/mTeCL08Ka97+yMusG6H4Pjr" +
            "p78H+zCjAgMBAAECggEAMh7yEHiUiB39AQQPoZ4aVoANK5m5IgcD+sy9YtTJkXq4" +
            "wKWirya2eEoShfTxJaDmtreT47BqySxBRmwJbM3eKDNOGAxq4GAke+PKT+LnnPB+" +
            "mBInoKsdOsmr5PYsmvpnTgoODzxColTCNS8+KPidJyzlE6Bq3RXWVffpxGgWhFnT" +
            "JM1MTpJJ/tKeZAUKOXbSU9T079gduPHTkrFeUnAt179ruSLov2Nbt8XhqDiY+pXm" +
            "EjMb+Q8JlBJ1F82i43BR6w6fjdSReGUNs8NDbmjpMasuk2U1/t28Idnt3M07jDUP" +
            "LGPrAeTZd/PLNpbflZMJoDT5SoCFycXNE3rHrsr8YQKBgQDveZzFcZctuYVd9iDd" +
            "SNLS6a2MuSwLrEPtUXRC7QR8BO2OkEvqMD5tVv3+a0ZPQpNg+4KzaKdzbsTNifpY" +
            "qjNzfydZ3CZzKlRVt/88icFxicWvI+fKiDdcGUt7agS4o9Ce+EkkqBySvVJB5Blz" +
            "vKLNyMQsJb2y6jRTekl/iO2XIQKBgQDW+9j128OmtPBERMw0RKxS5KZEYIhvZ+kw" +
            "lRe7D21o1d7MQx0zxKw58AWDW/epiVyno/FDuWmj2pQQ/oLpZl3ERg+hf3yUp48A" +
            "MziyuI3+INni/+uMWR3RN6sp4IbebXb6itGAIOm7ljgYwFV9crpLd7GZz3wi3/iZ" +
            "+zOVLl9DQwKBgQDXbYOGayUg0SAU4vG1n2loqyagzYO+DH4e44O/IRFDr/s0oMJq" +
            "LnQ6UGO1mDNr4exK9nchhif9Q8xvSoyXbqVSZTS1NcKxH4c2hYtqnlITHWlkoNxH" +
            "6jpC885fe4Q7xcJK//hsrX7m0sFI3TW4VB3xGYbAYENCzEW+QugTfs6dgQKBgQCi" +
            "nB5QYOkNWID/8lXPFz6M+Jv2zlmEgsF0WOF5QUMNb++06vLUrGdk73MMF+0tlFO8" +
            "DZo5Eq6gHH2wmQImTqKQCjpaepadzluw2A2DyWrFlM2aEN926hVOod/arhT1ezDq" +
            "c0PhuYNxuz81IY3IdJYK7T8tyy3nJyfgOIycw1WVBwKBgQDQ+iZpSMp1wIqnIeNb" +
            "zdlaVYXBu7d0tBlG/JGnPRlNVJkVpKd4woWtMwkqMGuAmmSkdjzhFYca9SWgzV1R" +
            "gzQzf1GuClF8KO7drdyvKGNqDFhyuCgE9mXI34ovjNcva9u+aZGHxuEYlCTKA0cV" +
            "UT/0leMkegvP/kFKOvzfYRBNFg==";
    byte[] encodedPrivateKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyPem);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedPrivateKey);
    return (PrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8EncodedKeySpec);
}
```

Now the code - paste it between "//System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");" and "SSLServerSocket serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket) ctx.getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(PORT);" and delete a code lines between. Paste in this code lines:

```
    //Create a temp truststore with the server certificate
    KeyStore ksTemp = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ksTemp.load(null, null); //Initialize it
    ksTemp.setCertificateEntry("Alias", getcertificate());
    ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // save the temp keystore
    ksTemp.store(bOut, "passphrase".toCharArray());
    //Now create the keystore to be used by jsse
    KeyStore keyStoreTs = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    keyStoreTs.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(bOut.toByteArray()), "passphrase".toCharArray());

    // now lets do the same with the keystore
    KeyStore ksTemp2 = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ksTemp2.load(null, null); //Initialize it
    ksTemp2.setCertificateEntry("Alias", getcertificate());
    ByteArrayOutputStream bOut2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // save the temp keystore
    ksTemp2.store(bOut2, "passphrase".toCharArray());
    //Now create the keystore to be used by jsse
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    keyStore.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(bOut2.toByteArray()), "passphrase".toCharArray());
    X509Certificate[] chain = new X509Certificate[1];
    chain[0] = getcertificate();
    keyStore.setKeyEntry("privateCert", getPrivateKey(), "passphrase".toCharArray(), chain);

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(keyStoreTs);

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(keyStore, "passphrase".toCharArray());

    // create SSLContext to establish the secure connection
    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance(TLS_PROTOCOL);
    ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

Again a warning: this is rough code - check yourself to get it secured!

Running the server and asking for a connection with `https://localhost:32333/` the server protocol shows:

```
Server started on port 32333
Accept new connection: /127.0.0.1:58640
Server received 375 bytes: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:32333
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0


Accept new connection: /127.0.0.1:58642
Server received 331 bytes: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:32333
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0
Accept: image/webp,*/*
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://localhost:32333/
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

My browser (Firefox) shows this data:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:32333
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Well, that should solve your problem. Happy weekend.

Comment: This is a lot more complicated and convoluted than needed; the only relevant point is running the privatekey through a KeyFactory as PKCS8, and putting the result in the keystore used.

Comment: Thank you for this extended example Michael Fehr. It is working fine. My problem was the private key conversion. I accept the answer from dave_thompson_085, since it just 3 lines I need to replace in my example.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably **not an answer** but for the sake of better reading I'm using this. Below is my sample code for a TLS server using version 1.3 (source is taken from https://blog.gypsyengineer.com/en/security/an-example-of-tls-13-client-and-server-on-java.html).

The important fact is to have a keystore **and** a truststore available at startup of the server and use (I'm binding them using "System.setProperty" instead of "-Djavax.net...").

Maybe this helps you in finding a solution on your own :-)

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.*;

/*
 * Don't forget to set the following system properties when you run the class:
 *
 *     javax.net.ssl.keyStore
 *     javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword
 *     javax.net.ssl.trustStore
 *     javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword
 *
 * More details can be found in JSSE docs.
 *
 * For example:
 *
 *     java -cp classes \
 *         -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore \
 *         -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=passphrase \
 *         -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=keystore \
 *         -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=passphrase \
 *             com.gypsyengineer.tlsbunny.jsse.TLSv13Test
 *
 * For testing purposes, you can download the keystore file from
 *
 *     https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/test/jdk/javax/net/ssl/etc
 */

public class TLSv13Test {
    // source: https://blog.gypsyengineer.com/en/security/an-example-of-tls-13-client-and-server-on-java.html
    private static final int delay = 1000; // in millis
    private static final String[] protocols = new String[] {"TLSv1.3"};
    private static final String[] cipher_suites = new String[] {"TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"};
    private static final String message =
            "Like most of life's problems, this one can be solved with bending!";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // system settings for keystores
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "keystores\\tls\\keystore");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "passphrase");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "keystores\\tls\\truststore");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "passphrase");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");

        try (EchoServer server = EchoServer.create()) {
            new Thread(server).start();
            Thread.sleep(delay);

            try (SSLSocket socket = createSocket("localhost", server.port())) {
                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                os.write(message.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                byte[] data = new byte[2048];
                int len = is.read(data);
                if (len <= 0) {
                    throw new IOException("no data received");
                }
                System.out.printf("client received %d bytes: %s%n",
                        len, new String(data, 0, len));
            }
        }
    }

    public static SSLSocket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()
                .createSocket(host, port);
        socket.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
        socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(cipher_suites);
        return socket;
    }

    public static class EchoServer implements Runnable, AutoCloseable {
        private static final int FREE_PORT = 0;
        private final SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket;
        private EchoServer(SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket) {
            this.sslServerSocket = sslServerSocket;
        }

        public int port() {
            return sslServerSocket.getLocalPort();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            if (sslServerSocket != null && !sslServerSocket.isClosed()) {
                sslServerSocket.close();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.printf("server started on port %d%n", port());

            try (SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept()) {
                System.out.println("accepted");
                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                byte[] data = new byte[2048];
                int len = is.read(data);
                if (len <= 0) {
                    throw new IOException("no data received");
                }
                System.out.printf("server received %d bytes: %s%n",
                        len, new String(data, 0, len));
                os.write(data, 0, len);
                os.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.printf("exception: %s%n", e.getMessage());
            }

            System.out.println("server stopped");
        }

        public static EchoServer create() throws IOException {
            return create(FREE_PORT);
        }

        public static EchoServer create(int port) throws IOException {
            SSLServerSocket socket = (SSLServerSocket)
                    SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(port);
            socket.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
            socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(cipher_suites);
            return new EchoServer(socket);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this example. Actually my sample code is based on this. Unfortunately it does not solve my issue, since the key aspect of my goal is to use the keys in the given format in memory and do not point to any store references on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, to add to @Michael Fehr answer, below is the working client side portion to go with it.

*However, if anyone can list out the keytool or openssl steps to recreate a chained certificate like the one used, please respond to my post*, thanks and enjoy!
This is my first post appreciate any reps.

In TlsClient.java put this:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

public class TlsClient {

private static final String[] CIPHER_SUITES = new String[] {
        "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
};
private static final int PORT = 32333;
private static final String TLS_PROTOCOL = "TLSv1.3";

public static X509Certificate getcertificate() throws CertificateException {
    String certificate = "MIIDSzCCAjMCBFc5m4cwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwajELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxCzAJ" +
            "BgNVBAgMAkNBMRIwEAYDVQQHDAlDdXBlcnRpbm8xDjAMBgNVBAoMBUR1bW15MQ4w" +
            "DAYDVQQLDAVEdW1teTEaMBgGA1UEAwwRZHVtbXkuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20wHhcNMTYw" +
            "NTE2MTAwNjM4WhcNMjYwNTE2MTAwNjM4WjBqMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzELMAkGA1UE" +
            "CAwCQ0ExEjAQBgNVBAcMCUN1cGVydGlubzEOMAwGA1UECgwFRHVtbXkxDjAMBgNV" +
            "BAsMBUR1bW15MRowGAYDVQQDDBFkdW1teS5leGFtcGxlLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZI" +
            "hvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMkbQD5byG7xnyOWVzeIwbtHVPem/LJlXAHc" +
            "WJwz8pZ75rGBnZmAtgunXU++yPTZZOgYTZpM+qQhrFy2Z1Di/vVzhlVpcOZBw1RB" +
            "lI3s2uQYaWVtBtKtNELYWXEbhfxVJFBs5lLmsYJufVasMT+3XzBERuIEUV43JTKS" +
            "5ttwkoVgYRX6KDrIj0hYA7ZmOB/y5E1BG2mLsSkX0SoTCpuhgYwlWO4kvYoGu9vH" +
            "SfugUzQBqSiE1yN+Qfl3+76U23Pmbm/by9n3M3AoULxk2XnQmgBYtzViV0f1E3rr" +
            "/77XvIydWLHB0kotpND+ZN4IvTwpr3v7Iy6wbofg+Ounvwf7MKMCAwEAATANBgkq" +
            "hkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAWRWiibTf9UZAlXr+2ZmBMMMONpBOUaSbexLNs6MahBmj" +
            "cdEwOQ+l5xAdV4xVEDoDhu0m1JeDXy6SXo7mYkM2l9u/uz7tRStuEiM+tbCDaclb" +
            "W/H5QOdpiIx9uh86cEgBpk4xUO5vSaLI/9uSKgGkTNAFrjy3ME3wfc0cd5ntS8ca" +
            "8xobcmQ59SYZb9Gi0u/YN9yro9RwGDL8O1Bmp9+9rn5hor/oOVGHlbz2MN43moSZ" +
            "EiIfegW9OWiaWqIGqBOXvoEGp0exN+lhhmonI3zdYCB0jss2QYm3E1IWqZUkNOg3" +
            "yulIxph3FYvF+cA/vTVlohq5VB3DsCrnkDmqbU2mlw==";
    byte[] encodedCertificate = Base64.getDecoder().decode(certificate);
    CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    return (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(encodedCertificate));
}

public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    String privateKeyPem = "MIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQDJG0A+W8hu8Z8j" +
            "llc3iMG7R1T3pvyyZVwB3FicM/KWe+axgZ2ZgLYLp11Pvsj02WToGE2aTPqkIaxc" +
            "tmdQ4v71c4ZVaXDmQcNUQZSN7NrkGGllbQbSrTRC2FlxG4X8VSRQbOZS5rGCbn1W" +
            "rDE/t18wREbiBFFeNyUykubbcJKFYGEV+ig6yI9IWAO2Zjgf8uRNQRtpi7EpF9Eq" +
            "EwqboYGMJVjuJL2KBrvbx0n7oFM0AakohNcjfkH5d/u+lNtz5m5v28vZ9zNwKFC8" +
            "ZNl50JoAWLc1YldH9RN66/++17yMnVixwdJKLaTQ/mTeCL08Ka97+yMusG6H4Pjr" +
            "p78H+zCjAgMBAAECggEAMh7yEHiUiB39AQQPoZ4aVoANK5m5IgcD+sy9YtTJkXq4" +
            "wKWirya2eEoShfTxJaDmtreT47BqySxBRmwJbM3eKDNOGAxq4GAke+PKT+LnnPB+" +
            "mBInoKsdOsmr5PYsmvpnTgoODzxColTCNS8+KPidJyzlE6Bq3RXWVffpxGgWhFnT" +
            "JM1MTpJJ/tKeZAUKOXbSU9T079gduPHTkrFeUnAt179ruSLov2Nbt8XhqDiY+pXm" +
            "EjMb+Q8JlBJ1F82i43BR6w6fjdSReGUNs8NDbmjpMasuk2U1/t28Idnt3M07jDUP" +
            "LGPrAeTZd/PLNpbflZMJoDT5SoCFycXNE3rHrsr8YQKBgQDveZzFcZctuYVd9iDd" +
            "SNLS6a2MuSwLrEPtUXRC7QR8BO2OkEvqMD5tVv3+a0ZPQpNg+4KzaKdzbsTNifpY" +
            "qjNzfydZ3CZzKlRVt/88icFxicWvI+fKiDdcGUt7agS4o9Ce+EkkqBySvVJB5Blz" +
            "vKLNyMQsJb2y6jRTekl/iO2XIQKBgQDW+9j128OmtPBERMw0RKxS5KZEYIhvZ+kw" +
            "lRe7D21o1d7MQx0zxKw58AWDW/epiVyno/FDuWmj2pQQ/oLpZl3ERg+hf3yUp48A" +
            "MziyuI3+INni/+uMWR3RN6sp4IbebXb6itGAIOm7ljgYwFV9crpLd7GZz3wi3/iZ" +
            "+zOVLl9DQwKBgQDXbYOGayUg0SAU4vG1n2loqyagzYO+DH4e44O/IRFDr/s0oMJq" +
            "LnQ6UGO1mDNr4exK9nchhif9Q8xvSoyXbqVSZTS1NcKxH4c2hYtqnlITHWlkoNxH" +
            "6jpC885fe4Q7xcJK//hsrX7m0sFI3TW4VB3xGYbAYENCzEW+QugTfs6dgQKBgQCi" +
            "nB5QYOkNWID/8lXPFz6M+Jv2zlmEgsF0WOF5QUMNb++06vLUrGdk73MMF+0tlFO8" +
            "DZo5Eq6gHH2wmQImTqKQCjpaepadzluw2A2DyWrFlM2aEN926hVOod/arhT1ezDq" +
            "c0PhuYNxuz81IY3IdJYK7T8tyy3nJyfgOIycw1WVBwKBgQDQ+iZpSMp1wIqnIeNb" +
            "zdlaVYXBu7d0tBlG/JGnPRlNVJkVpKd4woWtMwkqMGuAmmSkdjzhFYca9SWgzV1R" +
            "gzQzf1GuClF8KO7drdyvKGNqDFhyuCgE9mXI34ovjNcva9u+aZGHxuEYlCTKA0cV" +
            "UT/0leMkegvP/kFKOvzfYRBNFg==";
    byte[] encodedPrivateKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyPem);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedPrivateKey);
    return (PrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8EncodedKeySpec);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new TlsClient().start();
}

private void start() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");

    // String ksPw = "canEdit";

    // Create a temp truststore with the server certificate
    KeyStore ksTemp = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ksTemp.load(null, null); // Initialize it
    ksTemp.setCertificateEntry("Alias", getcertificate());
    ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // save the temp keystore
    ksTemp.store(bOut, "passphrase".toCharArray());
    // Now create the keystore to be used by jsse
    KeyStore keyStoreTs = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    keyStoreTs.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(bOut.toByteArray()), "passphrase".toCharArray());

    // now lets do the same with the keystore
    KeyStore ksTemp2 = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ksTemp2.load(null, null); // Initialize it
    ksTemp2.setCertificateEntry("Alias", getcertificate());
    ByteArrayOutputStream bOut2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // save the temp keystore
    ksTemp2.store(bOut2, "passphrase".toCharArray());
    // Now create the keystore to be used by jsse
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    keyStore.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(bOut2.toByteArray()), "passphrase".toCharArray());
    X509Certificate[] chain = new X509Certificate[1];
    chain[0] = getcertificate();
    keyStore.setKeyEntry("privateCert", getPrivateKey(), "passphrase".toCharArray(), chain);

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(keyStoreTs);

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(keyStore, "passphrase".toCharArray());

    // create SSLContext to establish the secure connection
    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance(TLS_PROTOCOL);
    ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

    // Socket connection.
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) ctx.getSocketFactory().createSocket("localhost", PORT);
    socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(CIPHER_SUITES);
    socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {
            TLS_PROTOCOL });

    System.out.println("Connected: " + socket.isConnected());
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    os.write("Hello World".getBytes());
    os.flush();
    byte[] data = new byte[2048];
    int len = is.read(data);
    if (len <= 0) {
        throw new IOException("No data received.");
    }
        System.out.printf("Client received %d bytes: %s%n", len, new String(data, 0, len));
    }
}
```